# __device__ __constant__ const

Tags: cuda

Is there any difference and what is the best way to define device constants in a CUDA program? In the C++, host/device program if I want to define constants to be in device constant memory I can do either

```
__device__ __constant__ float a = 5;
__constant__ float a = 5;
```

Question 1. On devices 2.x and CUDA 4, is it the same as,

```
__device__ const float a = 5;
```

Question 2. Why is it that in PyCUDA SourceModule("""..."""), which compiles only do device code, even the following works?

```
const float a = 5;
```

Comment: Question 3. Is this homework?

Comment: It reads like homework. If it's homework, please add a `homework` label, and you probably also want `c++` so you'll get some responses. I can't answer it, personally. I don't know anything about CUDA.

Answer (score 8):

In CUDA `__constant__`is a variable type qualifier that indicates the variable being declared is to be stored in *device constant memory*. Quoting [section B 2.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant) of the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)

> The `__constant__` qualifier, optionally used together with `__device__`,
>   declares a variable that:
>
> - Resides in constant memory space,
> - Has the lifetime of an application,
> - Is accessible from all the threads
>     within the grid and from the host through the runtime library
>     ([`cudaGetSymbolAddress()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g3a0f010e70a3343db18227cec9615177) / [`cudaGetSymbolSize()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g1d150bde14df4e291b520226fe475466) / [`cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9bcf02b53644eee2bef9983d807084c7) /
>     [`cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17ce3365ef7b6687a7d16c5b29de1f82) for the runtime API and [`cuModuleGetGlobal()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE_1gf3e43672e26073b1081476dbf47a86ab) for
>     the driver API).

In CUDA, constant memory is a dedicated, static, global memory area accessed via a cache (there are a dedicated set of PTX load instructions for its purpose) which are uniform and read-only for all threads in a running kernel. But the contents of constant memory can be modified at runtime through the use of the host side APIs quoted above. This is different from declaring a variable to the compiler using the `const` declaration, which is adding a read-only characteristic to a variable at the scope of the declaration. The two are not at all the same thing.

Comment: "Alternatively, on devices of compute capability 2.x, programs use the LoaD Uniform (LDU) operation; see Section F.4.4 of the CUDA C Programming Guide for details" (3.2.5 Constant Memory of CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf).

Comment: "In addition to the constant memory space supported by devices of all compute capabilities (where __constant__ variables reside), devices of compute capability 2.x support the LDU (LoaD Uniform) instruction that the compiler uses to load any variable that is:
* pointing to global memory,
* read-only in the kernel (programmer can enforce this using the const keyword),
* not dependent on thread ID."

Comment: So I guess, I'm asking which is better (or are they the same) for compute capability 2.x device: `__constant__` (via PTX load instructions) or `const` via (LDU)?