# Constant memory symbol as static property of class

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm sorry for the bad title...
I would like to have a class  with a static property value that I could use in device code.  What I tried s the following:

```
struct MyConstValue
{
    static __constant__ int value;
};
```

In theory, now, I should define MyConstValue::value, initialize it, probably through `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`, then I could write a kernel that access this value through `MyGlobalValue::value`.

If I add

```
int __constant__ MyConstValue::value;
```

for the sake of defining the symbol (both with and without `__constant__`), nvcc outputs

```
error: ‘static’ may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member [-fpermissive]
```

Is there a way to implement my idea?

I'm using CUDA 5.5, I target compute capabilities > 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for static class members in CUDA.

The reason might be that there is no defined point at which it would be initialized, if all threads would do so, or if just one, and if so, which thread. So static data just doesn't make sense in this context.

From the [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/573203/why-is-there-no-support-for-static-class-members-/):

> But what would a "static class member" idiom even mean on a GPU? It
>   can't be the same as the GPU since there's so many new questions about
>   its definition. Perhaps every thread has its own static member, even
>   if that thread accesses multiple copies of the class? Every block has
>   a single static member? Every kernel? Every DEVICE, since classes can
>   live in memory beyond kernel invocations?

From B 2.2 of the CUDA programming guide:

> The **constant** qualifier, optionally used together with **device**,
>   declares a variable that:
>
> Resides in constant memory space, Has the lifetime of an application,
>   Is accessible from all the threads within the grid and from the host
>   through the runtime library (cudaGetSymbolAddress() /
>   cudaGetSymbolSize() / cudaMemcpyToSymbol() / cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()
>   for the runtime API and cuModuleGetGlobal() for the driver API).

You may take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7963395/1141471).

Comment: So, the answer is no, I cannot do that.  I'll have to find another solution.  Many thanks!